# shell script put result of curl in variable followed by sleep command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl

I want to trigger curl requests every 400ms in shell script and put the results in a variable, and after finishing the curl request (eg 10 requests) finally write all results in a file. when I use the following code for this purpose

```
result="$(curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8087/say-hello')" & sleep 0.400;
```

Because **&** creates a new process result can not achieve. so what should I do?

Comment: The `&` is wrong, I suppose you meant `&&`

Comment: No, it is single & because I want to execute the first command in the background and don't wait to complete

Comment: @tripleee No, it is a single & because I want to execute the first command in the background and don't wait to complete

Comment: A background process is _a separate process_. It can't set variables in the parent.

Comment: What's your actual purpose in using `sleep` and backgrounding the `curl`? You're telling us what implementation you want, but not what goal you expect that implementation to solve. If you told us the goal, not just the mechanism, we might be able to specify better ways to accomplish it.

Comment: (One approach that doesn't involve temporary files on disk, for example, might involve using a process substitution to retrieve the output of each `curl`; but whether that's actually usefully responsive to your question depends on details that haven't been specified)

Comment: ...see also the "XY problem" (I want to do thing-X, and think thing-Y might be a way to do that, so I'm asking how to do Y... even though there might in fact be a better or more correct way to accomplish X that doesn't involve Y at all).

Comment: In this part of my program actually, I want to trigger curl requests every 400ms and put the results in a variable, and after finishing the curl request (eg 10 requests) finally write results in a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-m` curl option instead of the sleep.

```
       -m, --max-time <seconds>
              Maximum time in seconds that you allow the  whole  operation  to
              take.   This is useful for preventing your batch jobs from hang‐
              ing for hours due to slow networks or  links  going  down.   See
              also the --connect-timeout option.
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference can be sound in the next sequence of commands:

```
a=1; a=$(echo 2) ; sleep 1; echo $a
2
```

and with a background process

```
a=1; a=$(echo 2) & sleep 1; echo $a
[1] 973
[1]+  Done                    a=$(echo 2)
1
```

Why is `a` not changed in the second case?
Actually it is changed... in a new environment. The `&` creates a new process with its own `a`, and that `a` is assigned the value 2. When the process is finished, the variable `a` of that subprocess is deleted and you only of the original value of `a`.

Depending on your requirements you might want to make a `resultdir`, have every background `curl` process write to a different tmpfile, wait with `wait` until all curls are finished and collect your results.